# How to override a component's default props and export it as a new component in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am working on a component library based on Bootstrap and I am developing a `Base` component which most Bootstrap's classes are defined as properties. It means that some of the properties are mapped to Bootstrap's CSS classes.

For example the below code:

```html
<Base container="lg" mb="2" p="3">...</Base>
```

will be rendered to:

```html
<div class="container-lg mb-2 p-3">...</div> `
```

To develop a `Card` component, I just need to set a few defaults to `Base` component properties.

I create a new `Card.svelte` file and import the `Base` component (component composition).

Also, I exported all components in `index.js`:

```js
import Base from './Base.svelte';    
import Card from './Card.svelte';    
import Col from './Col.svelte';    
export { Col, Card, Base }
```

Here is a simple [Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/260f190800f84ec18936f6acb5c80f86?version=3.55.0)

Is there anyway to define `Card`, `Col`, etc. components without creating an individual file for each? Something like this:

```js
import Base from './Base.svelte';

const Card = // Base({ continer: "lg", mb:"3", p: "3", tag: "div" })
const Col = // Base({ col: "6", tag: "div" })

export { Col, Card, Base }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge in the props using the [client-side API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api), e.g.:

```js
export function Card({ props, ...rest }) {
    return new Base({
        props: {
            container: "lg",
            mb: "3",
            p: "3",
            tag: "div",
            ...props,
        },
        ...rest
    });
}
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/f49f6066b71a47a7a15cfa7c078b86a6?version=3.55.0)

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there any issue on SSR with this approach?

Comment: Possibly, though I do not know how that could be fixed. If all fails this would be another case for pre-processing or code generation.