# How can I use a component as a variable when using Svelte and Carbon Components?

Tags: typescript, svelte, carbon-components, carbon-components-svelte

When using Carbon Component for Svelte, is it possible to assign a component as a variable, and then pass that variable to a prop?

For example, I'm using the `<Modal />` component, whose primary button exposes a `primaryButtonIcon` [prop](https://svelte.carbondesignsystem.com/components/Modal#props); I want to assign different icons depending on the state.

Something like this:

```
let uploadStatus: "active" | "inactive" | "finished" | "error" | undefined = "active";
let primaryButtonIcon: WHAT? = <InlineLoading status={uploadStatus} />;

<Modal primaryButtonIcon={primaryButtonIcon} />
```

But what should I declare the `primaryButtonIcon` as?

---

**UPDATE:**
When I use ...

```
let uploadStatus: "active" | "inactive" | "finished" | "error" | undefined = "active";
let primaryButtonIcon: typeof SvelteComponent<any> = <InlineLoading status={uploadStatus} />;
```

... there are errors ...

[image]

The error relating to `uploadStatus` is ...

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'uploadStatus'. ts(2451)

The error relating to `primaryButtonIcon` is ...

> Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'SvelteComponentTyped<InlineLoadingProps, { click: MouseEvent; mouseover: MouseEvent; mouseenter: MouseEvent; mouseleave: MouseEvent; success: CustomEvent<...>; }, {}>' but required in type 'typeof SvelteComponent'. ts(2741)

And the error relating to `<InlineLoading />` is ...

> Conversion of type 'string' to type 'InlineLoading' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. ts(2352)

Have I declared something wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is shown right in the docs in the "Type" column, it's the base component type from `svelte`, so:

```js
import { type SvelteComponent } from 'svelte';
let primaryButtonIcon: typeof SvelteComponent<any> = ...
```

(Though one should generally use `ComponentType` instead.)

But, you *cannot* define markup inline in Svelte.
It has to be extracted to a self-contained component file.

(In Svelte 5 snippets allow referencing pieces of markup in the script.)

Comment: I had already tried this, and it produces errors. I've updated the OP with more information.

Comment: As I said, that is invalid, you cannot just have markup in the script. You only can reference a component class, nothing else. E.g. `let primaryButtonIcon: typeof SvelteComponent<any> = MyLoadingComponent`. You could potentially define a function that wraps the component instantiation, returning a new component constructor, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75023024/how-to-override-a-components-default-props-and-export-it-as-a-new-component-in/).

Comment: When you wrote that "you cannot define markup inline in Svelte" I didn't appreciate that you were referring to props.